# Terminating app due to uncaught exception '_HKObjectValidationFailureException'

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

I am saving the blood glucose values into Health Kit application in iOS.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

    float bloodGlucose=20;   
    float bloodGlucoseValue= (int) bloodGlucose;   
    NSLog(@"Blood Glucose value is :%f",bloodGlucoseValue);   
    HKQuantityType *bloodGlucoseType=[HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBloodGlucose];

    NSSet *requesObjects=[[NSSet alloc]initWithObjects:bloodGlucoseType, nil];   
    HKHealthStore  * hStore = [HKHealthStore new];

    [hStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes: requesObjects readTypes:requesObjects completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

    //user response processing goes here, i.e.

    if(success) {          
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [[GSHealthKitManager sharedManager]saveBloodGlucosePercentageintoHealthStore:bloodGlucoseValue];

    });

    }

    }];

}

-(void)saveBloodGlucosePercentageintoHealthStore:(float)bloodGlucoseValue
{

HKUnit *inches=[HKUnit gramUnit];
HKQuantity * glucoseQuantity = [HKQuantity quantityWithUnit:inches doubleValue:bloodGlucoseValue];

HKQuantityType *glucoseType = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBloodGlucose]; 
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];  
HKQuantitySample *bloodGlucosesample = [HKQuantitySample quantitySampleWithType:glucoseType quantity:glucoseQuantity startDate:now endDate:now];

[self.healthStore saveObject:bloodGlucosesample withCompletion:^(BOOL  success, NSError *error){

if (!success)           
{

NSLog(@"Error");

}

}];

}
```

If I run the application, I got following exception in this line of code:

```
HKQuantitySample *bloodGlucosesample = [HKQuantitySample quantitySampleWithType:glucoseType quantity:glucoseQuantity startDate:now endDate:now];
```

Trace:

```
Exception is: Terminating app due to uncaught exception '_HKObjectValidationFailureException', reason: 'HKQuantitySample 20 g 2016-04-07 15:39:44 +0530 2016-04-07 15:39:44 +0530 requires unit of type Mass/Volume. Incompatible unit: g'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00b73a14 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00634e02 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00b7393d +[NSException raise:format:] + 141
    3   HealthKit                           0x0010da70 -[HKObject _validateForCreation] + 149
    4   HealthKit                           0x0010d89e +[HKObject _newDataObjectWithMetadata:device:config:] + 273
    5   HealthKit                           0x0014e661 +[HKSample _newSampleWithType:startDate:endDate:device:metadata:config:] + 200
    6   HealthKit                           0x0013244f +[HKQuantitySample quantitySampleWithType:quantity:startDate:endDate:device:metadata:] + 324
    7   HealthKit                           0x0013265a +[HKQuantitySample quantitySampleWithType:quantity:startDate:endDate:] + 116
    8   HealthKitProto                      0x0005cda2 -[GSHealthKitManager saveBloodGlucosePercentageintoHealthStore:] + 274
    9   HealthKitProto                      0x0005f4c7 __34-[FirstViewController viewDidLoad]_block_invoke_9 + 103
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0367a377 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0369d9cd _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03682f90 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 910
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00ac4fde __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00a82cd4 __CFRunLoopRun + 2356
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00a820e6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00a81efb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x04523664 GSEventRunModal + 192
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x045234a1 GSEventRun + 104
    19  UIKit                               0x00f02bfa UIApplicationMain + 160
    20  HealthKitProto                      0x000603ba main + 138
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x036c7a21 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: help me anybody.. plzzz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that grams is not an unit supported by healthkit.

Check the allowed units in the [SDK documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKQuantitySample_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/HKQuantitySample/quantity) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HealthKit_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Results_Identifiers)

**Edit:** You specify a bad unit for this value

```
HKUnit *inches=[HKUnit gramUnit]; // this is not the right unit (nor inches)
HKQuantity * glucoseQuantity = [HKQuantity quantityWithUnit:inches doubleValue:bloodGlucoseValue];
```

You should create a mass unit and volume unit then divide the first by the second one (in swift):

```
let milligramPerDeciLiter = HKUnit.gramUnitWithMetricPrefix(.Milli).unitDividedByUnit(HKUnit.literUnitWithMetricPrefix(.Deci))
```

In Objc :

```
HKUnit* milligramPerDeciLiter = [[HKUnit gramUnitWithMetricPrefix:HKMetricPrefixMilli] unitDividedByUnit:[HKUnit literUnitWithMetricPrefix:HKMetricPrefixDeci]];
```

Comment: actually in health kit application they are mentioning mg/dL in blood glucose

Comment: @satya From your error message `HKQuantitySample 20 g` ... `requires unit of type Mass/Volume. Incompatible unit: g'`. So check your input.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Basically, your unit should be `let milligramPerDeciLiter = HKUnit.gramUnitWithMetricPrefix(.Milli).unitDividedByUnit(HKUnit.literUnitWithMetricPrefix(.Deci))`

Comment: i have no idea about swift.. will you guide me in objective-c plz don't mind bro plz help me.. it is urgent task

Comment: thanks bro its working awesome.. will you explain me. or give me any little bit idea.. what u r change.. etc details. please i want to know.. thank u so much

Comment: You specified g unit instead of mg/dL, I've just changed the unit to the right one.