# Determining crash on HKObject _validateForCreation

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, healthkit

While testing on device (Apple Watch) attempting to save an `HKWorkout` into `HealthKit` I am adding samples of distance samples, calories, heart rates and vo2Max to the workout.  Unfortunately unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473745/terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-hkobjectvalidationfailureexception) I am not getting as detailed as a trace back...as far as I can tell it's crashing on adding a sample but I can't tell which sample it is or why?

Code:

```
 private func addSamples(toWorkout workout: HKWorkout, from startDate: Date, to endDate: Date, handler: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void) {


        let vo2MaxSample = HKQuantitySample(type: HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.vo2Max)!, quantity: vo2MaxQuantity(), start: startDate, end: endDate)

        var samples = [HKQuantitySample]()

        for distanceWalkingRunningSample in distanceWalkingRunningSamples {
            samples.append(distanceWalkingRunningSample)
        }

        for energySample in energySamples {
            samples.append(energySample)
        }

        samples.append(vo2MaxSample)
        samples.append(contentsOf: heartRateValues)

        // Add samples to workout
        healthStore.add(samples, to: workout) { (success: Bool, error: Error?) in

            if error != nil {
                print("Adding workout subsamples failed with error: \(String(describing: error))")
                handler(false, error)
            }

            if success {
                print("Success, samples have been added, workout Saved.")  //WorkoutStartDate = \(workout.startDate) WorkoutEndDate = \(workout.endDate)
                handler(true, nil)

            } else {
                print("Adding workout subsamples failed no error reported")
                handler(false, nil)
            }

        }
    }
```

Trace:

```
     Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
            Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
            Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
            Triggered by Thread:  0

            Application Specific Information:
            abort() called

            Filtered syslog:
            None found

            Last Exception Backtrace:
            0   CoreFoundation                  0x1bdf75e8 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
            1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1b15717c objc_exception_throw + 33
            2   CoreFoundation                  0x1bdf752c +[NSException raise:format:] + 103
            3   HealthKit                       0x273dbdde -[HKObject _validateForCreation] + 111
            4   HealthKit                       0x273dbc48 +[HKObject _newDataObjectWithMetadata:device:config:] + 219
            5   HealthKit                       0x273dbb30 +[HKSample _newSampleWithType:startDate:endDate:device:metadata:config:] + 159
            6   HealthKit                       0x273e9ba8 +[HKWorkout _workoutWithActivityType:startDate:endDate:workoutEvents:duration:totalActiveEnergyBurned:totalBasalEnergyBurned:totalDistance:totalSwimmingStrokeCount:totalFlightsClimbed:goalType:goal:device:metadata:config:] + 431
            7   HealthKit                       0x274a9342 +[HKWorkout workoutWithActivityType:startDate:endDate:workoutEvents:totalEnergyBurned:totalDistance:device:metadata:] + 109
            8   HealthKit                       0x274a9160 +[HKWorkout workoutWithActivityType:startDate:endDate:workoutEvents:totalEnergyBurned:totalDistance:metadata:] + 87
    9   Watch Extension                 0x002b7ecc 0x290000 + 163532
    10  Watch Extension                 0x002b79fc 0x290000 + 162300
    11  Watch Extension                 0x002bb7ac 0x290000 + 178092
    12  Watch Extension                 0x002ab9e8 0x290000 + 113128
    13  Watch Extension                 0x002a9660 0x290000 + 104032
    14  Watch Extension                 0x002a8f68 0x290000 + 102248
    15  Watch Extension                 0x002a7748 0x290000 + 96072
    16  libdispatch.dylib               0x1b8875ec _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 5
    17  libdispatch.dylib               0x1b8875c8 _dispatch_client_callout + 1
    18  libdispatch.dylib               0x1b897822 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 853
    19  CoreFoundation                  0x1bdb31ac __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 5
    20  CoreFoundation                  0x1bdb0f42 __CFRunLoopRun + 929
    21  CoreFoundation                  0x1bcfe96a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 349
    22  GraphicsServices                0x1d8beb92 GSEventRunModal + 89
    23  UIKit                           0x21f556da UIApplicationMain + 151
    24  libxpc.dylib                    0x1bb2fd78 _xpc_objc_main + 581
    25  libxpc.dylib                    0x1bb31720 xpc_main + 149
    26  Foundation                      0x1c7bbf24 -[NSXPCListener resume] + 175
    27  PlugInKit                       0x22ccbf40 -[PKService run] + 709
    28  WatchKit                        0x2b5777b8 main + 157
    29  libdyld.dylib                   0x1b8e2b8e 0x1b8df000 + 15246

    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1b9e443c __pthread_kill + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1baec270 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 334
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x1b96d28e abort + 106
    3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x1b136cfe __cxa_bad_cast + 0
    4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x1b136e8a default_unexpected_handler+ 16010 () + 0
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1b1573e0 _objc_terminate+ 29664 () + 102
    6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x1b1493fc std::__terminate(void (*)+ 91132 ()) + 6
    7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x1b148ed6 __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func+ 89814 (_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 0
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1b157274 _objc_exception_destructor+ 29300 (void*) + 0
    9   CoreFoundation                  0x1bdf7530 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
    10  HealthKit                       0x273dbde2 -[HKObject _validateForCreation] + 116
    11  HealthKit                       0x273dbc4c +[HKObject _newDataObjectWithMetadata:device:config:] + 224
    12  HealthKit                       0x273dbb34 +[HKSample _newSampleWithType:startDate:endDate:device:metadata:config:] + 164
    13  HealthKit                       0x273e9bac +[HKWorkout _workoutWithActivityType:startDate:endDate:workoutEvents:duration:totalActiveEnergyBurned:totalBasalEnergyBurned:totalDistance:totalSwimmingStrokeCount:totalFlightsClimbed:goalType:goal:device:metadata:config:] + 436
    14  HealthKit                       0x274a9346 +[HKWorkout workoutWithActivityType:startDate:endDate:workoutEvents:totalEnergyBurned:totalDistance:device:metadata:] + 114
    15  HealthKit                       0x274a9164 +[HKWorkout workoutWithActivityType:startDate:endDate:workoutEvents:totalEnergyBurned:totalDistance:metadata:] + 92
16  Watch Extension                 0x002b7ed0 0x290000 + 163536
17  Watch Extension                 0x002b7a00 0x290000 + 162304
18  Watch Extension                 0x002bb7b0 0x290000 + 178096
19  Watch Extension                 0x002ab9ec 0x290000 + 113132
20  Watch Extension                 0x002a9664 0x290000 + 104036
21  Watch Extension                 0x002a8f6c 0x290000 + 102252
22  Watch Extension                 0x002a774c 0x290000 + 96076
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x1b8875f0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x1b8875cc _dispatch_client_callout + 6
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x1b897826 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 858
26  CoreFoundation                  0x1bdb31b0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 10
27  CoreFoundation                  0x1bdb0f46 __CFRunLoopRun + 934
28  CoreFoundation                  0x1bcfe96e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 354
29  GraphicsServices                0x1d8beb96 GSEventRunModal + 94
30  UIKit                           0x21f556de UIApplicationMain + 156
31  libxpc.dylib                    0x1bb2fd7c _xpc_objc_main + 586
32  libxpc.dylib                    0x1bb31724 xpc_main + 154
33  Foundation                      0x1c7bbf28 service_connection_handler + 0
34  PlugInKit                       0x22ccbf44 -[PKService run] + 714
35  WatchKit                        0x2b5777bc main + 162
36  libdyld.dylib                   0x1b8e2b92 start + 2
```

Comment: maybe here HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.vo2Max)! because of force unwrapping

Comment: @MoazKhan I was looking at that but Apple's own sample code force unwraps those too:  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SpeedySloth/Listings/SpeedySloth_WatchKit_Extension_HKQuantityTypeExtension_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017338-SpeedySloth_WatchKit_Extension_HKQuantityTypeExtension_swift-DontLinkElementID_9

Comment: Try line to line debugging and figure out the line which is causing the issue then give the line number here. I believe that because of the force unwrap vo2max is nil which is then added in the sample array and which is in turn passed to the add function which causes the issue maybe. Still more data is required to debug properly.

Comment: Thanks @MoazKhan the problem is I can't replicate it, but I did optionalize the vo2Max value just in case that was the cause.

Comment: I've seen this crash in Xcode crash reporting. I'm not sure how often it happens but it must be pretty rare. Nothing helpful to add other than: You are not alone!